# IBM Watson Conversationへメッセージを送信しても正常な応答が得られない

Tags: watson-api

## 目的

IBM Watson ConversationのAPIを使ってアプリケーション開発を行いたい。

## 問題

IBM Watson ConversationのAPIの一つでメッセージをConversationに送信し、応答を受け取るAPIがあるのですが、期待したような動きをしてくれない。

問題となるAPIは以下
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message

## 問題詳細

BluemixでConversationのワークスペースを作成、シナリオ（Dialog）も作成して、Try it out!で動作を確認しました。Try it out!ではDialogはきちんとトリガーを認識し、Dialogを遷移していくことができました。
しかし、そのワークスペースに対して上記のAPIでメッセージを送信しているのですが、Dialogを遷移していくことができません。具体的には下記の様にメッセージを投げているのですが、応答に「解釈できませんでした。申し訳ありませんが違う表現を試していただけますか。」と戻ってきてしまいます。トリガーを認識していれば「どんな種類ですか？」と戻ってくるはずなのですが...。
APIのヘルプを見るとメッセージに「Turn on the lights」と入れると「Ok. Turning on the light.」となっているようなのですが。

#### リクエストのJSON

```
{
  "input": {
    "text": "美味しいものが食べたい"
  },
  "alternate_intents": true
}
```

#### 応答

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "グルメ",
      "confidence": 1
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "input": {
    "text": "美味しいものが食べたい"
  },
  "output": {
    "log_messages": [],
    "text": [
      "解釈できませんでした。申し訳ありませんが違う表現を試していただけますか。"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "その他"
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "0f794d0b-680f-48fc-ac93-1350194af2e5",
    "system": {
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "root"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "その他": [
          0
        ]
      },
      "branch_exited": true,
      "branch_exited_reason": "completed"
    }
  },
  "alternate_intents": true
}
```

Comment: 自己解決しました。問題はAPIではなく、Coversation上でのダイアログ（シナリオ）の組み方に問題がありました。

Comment: こちらの質問から時間が経って、似たような質問が別に投稿されました: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48392/19110

Comment: makoyang さん、ご質問から随分時間が経ってしまいましたが、もしよろしければ自己解決した際の解決法を[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？　スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答を推奨しています。お手すきの際に是非よろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>