# watson assistantとSlackを連携したがうまく返ってこない

Tags: bluemix, デプロイ, watson-api

Bluemixでwatson assistantのワークスペースを作成、シナリオ（Dialog）も作成して、Try it out!で動作を確認しました。Try it out!ではDialogはきちんとトリガーを認識しました。
しかし、Deploy OptionsでSlack と連携してSlackで会話させると、応答に「解釈できませんでした。申し訳ありませんが違う表現を試していただけますか。」と戻ってきてしまいます。トリガーを認識していれば「どんなものですか？」と戻ってくるはずなのですが...。

似た質問として [IBM Watson Conversationへメッセージを送信しても正常な応答が得られない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34943/19110) があるのですが、具体的な回答が投稿されていません。

どのようにすれば正しく組めるのでしょうか？